# what does docker build -f 12.Dockerfile -t docker.something.com/blah/postgresql:12 . mean?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I think the main question is complete. I am not familiar with docker and I would love if someone could break down for me the meaning of the following command:

```
docker build -f 12.Dockerfile -t docker.something.com/blah/postgresql:12 .
```

Comment: Which parts do you struggle with? As far as I see, both `-f` and `-t` are documented at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Comment: Have you looked at the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) for the build command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker build -f 12.Dockerfile -t docker.something.com/blah/postgresql:12 .`

Breaking it down:

`docker build` is using the docker cli to invoke the `build` command

`-f 12.Dockerfile` specifies the `12.Dockerfile` file as the Dockerfile you are trying to build

`-t docker.something.com/blah/postgresql:12` is specifying a tag which would be used to identify the build image

`.` is the docker context that tells docker that files and directories it would have access to, should it need to copy everything.

That said, you'd be better served by reading the documentation and familiarising yourself with these concepts